# Is it possible to use the .NET DataContractJSONSerializer to deserialize a JSON file formatted differently than it would usually serialize?

Tags: c#, json, datacontractjsonserializer

I have a JSON file formatted like so, which is generated by a tool that I cannot edit:

```
{
    "thing_name1": {
        "property1": 0,
        "property2": "sure"
    },
    "thing_name2": {
        "property1": 34,
        "property2": "absolutely"
    }
}
```

The class I'm trying to deserialize to is as such:

```
[DataContract]
public class Thing
{
    [DataMember]
    public String ThingName;

    [DataMember(Name="property1")]
    public int Property1;

    [DataMember(Name="property2")]
    public String Property2;
}
```

I need to put the values of "thing_name1" and "thing_name2" into the ThingName data member of their respective deserialized objects, but haven't been able to find an easy way to do this without writing a custom (de)serializer. Or writing a quick Python script to write another file, but that wouldn't be very space efficient.

Comment: Are you using `DataContractJsonSerializer` directly, or are you using WCF which is calling it internally?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid: there is an extra, outer `{ }`.  Upload to http://jsonlint.com/ and you will see an error.  Is that your actual JSON?  If not, can you share it?

Comment: I'm using DataContractJsonSerializer directly. Apologies on the JSON mistake in the post, that has been fixed. I'm not able to share the actual JSON being used, but if a solution will work with what is provided, it should work with my tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but you do need some custom code to do it.

It's a little ugly, but you can create a custom [`IDataContractSurrogate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.idatacontractsurrogate(v=vs.110).aspx) class to deserialize the JSON into a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>`, and then copy the values from the nested dictionary structure into a `List<Thing>`.  Here's the code you would need for the surrogate:

```
class MyDataContractSurrogate : IDataContractSurrogate
{
    public Type GetDataContractType(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(List<Thing>))
        {
            return typeof(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>);
        }
        return type;
    }

    public object GetDeserializedObject(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>) &&
            targetType == typeof(List<Thing>))
        {
            List<Thing> list = new List<Thing>();

            foreach (var kvp in (Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>)obj)
            {
                Thing thing = new Thing { ThingName = kvp.Key };
                Dictionary<string, object> propsDict = kvp.Value;

                foreach (PropertyInfo prop in GetDataMemberProperties(typeof(Thing)))
                {
                    DataMemberAttribute att = prop.GetCustomAttribute<DataMemberAttribute>();

                    object value;
                    if (propsDict.TryGetValue(att.Name, out value))
                    {
                        prop.SetValue(thing, value);
                    }
                }
                list.Add(thing);
            }

            return list;
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
    {
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(List<Thing>) &&
            targetType == typeof(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>))
        {
            var thingsDict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>();

            foreach (Thing thing in (List<Thing>)obj)
            {
                var propsDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (PropertyInfo prop in GetDataMemberProperties(typeof(Thing)))
                {
                    DataMemberAttribute att = prop.GetCustomAttribute<DataMemberAttribute>();
                    propsDict.Add(att.Name, prop.GetValue(thing));
                }
                thingsDict.Add(thing.ThingName, propsDict);
            }

            return thingsDict;
        }
        return obj;
    }

    private IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetDataMemberProperties(Type type)
    {
        return type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite && p.GetCustomAttribute<DataMemberAttribute>() != null);
    }

    // ------- The rest of these methods are not needed -------
    public object GetCustomDataToExport(Type clrType, Type dataContractType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object GetCustomDataToExport(MemberInfo memberInfo, Type dataContractType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void GetKnownCustomDataTypes(System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Type> customDataTypes)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Type GetReferencedTypeOnImport(string typeName, string typeNamespace, object customData)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration ProcessImportedType(System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration typeDeclaration, System.CodeDom.CodeCompileUnit compileUnit)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the surrogate, you'll need to create an instance of `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings` and pass it to the `DataContractJsonSerializer` with the following properties set.  Note that since we require the `UseSimpleDictionaryFormat` setting, this solution will only work with .Net 4.5 or later.

```
var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings();
settings.DataContractSurrogate = new MyDataContractSurrogate();
settings.KnownTypes = new List<Type> { typeof(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>) };
settings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true;
```

Note that in your `Thing` class you should NOT mark the `ThingName` member with a `[DataMember]` attribute, since it is handled specially in the surrogate.  Also, I made the assumption that your class members are actually *properties* (with `{ get; set; }`) and not *fields* like you wrote in your question.  If that assumption is incorrect, you'll need to change all the references to `PropertyInfo` in the surrogate code to use `FieldInfo` instead; otherwise the surrogate will not work.

```
[DataContract]
public class Thing
{
    // Don't mark this property with [DataMember]
    public string ThingName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "property1")]
    public int Property1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "property2")]
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a round-trip demo:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        {
          ""thing_name1"": {
            ""property1"": 0,
            ""property2"": ""sure""
          },
          ""thing_name2"": {
            ""property1"": 34,
            ""property2"": ""absolutely""
          }
        }";

        var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.DataContractSurrogate = new MyDataContractSurrogate();
        settings.KnownTypes = new List<Type> { typeof(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>) };
        settings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true;

        List<Thing> things = Deserialize<List<Thing>>(json, settings);

        foreach (Thing thing in things)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ThingName: " + thing.ThingName);
            Console.WriteLine("Property1: " + thing.Property1);
            Console.WriteLine("Property2: " + thing.Property2);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        json = Serialize(things, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string json, DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T), settings);
            return (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
        }
    }

    public static string Serialize(object obj, DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType(), settings);
            ser.WriteObject(ms, obj);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ThingName: thing_name1
Property1: 0
Property2: sure

ThingName: thing_name2
Property1: 34
Property2: absolutely

{"thing_name1":{"property1":0,"property2":"sure"},"thing_name2":{"property1":34,"property2":"absolutely"}}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! I ended up having to add a bit to account for a List<String> property I had, but for the purposes of the question, this is exactly what I was looking for.